# É possível retornar um vetor para um javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu estou desenvolvendo gráficos customizáveis pelos usuários onde ele pode selecionar as opções que querem,envio os **parâmetros** para o **php** que busca no banco de dados **sql** e me retorna o que eu quero.
Para os gráficos estou utilizando highcharts.
Mas eu estou com dificuldade em entender como eu retorno o vetor da minha função para o js.
Estou usando jquery para não precisar dar refresh na página.
Mas quando eu faço

```
$.post('envia.php', {nome: nome}
```

Ele realiza a busca dos dados,mas eu nao sei como volto esses dados para a minha página onde os gráficos são gerados.
Alguem saberia a solução?

Comment: Queres ajuda no PHP ou no JavaScript?

Comment: @Sergio Nos dois,pois não sei se é possível retornar um vetor para o javascript e percorre-lo normal.E alguma maneira de chamar a função do arquivo php pelo js.Obg

Comment: Para o JavaScript o bfavaretto já respondeu, pois o `$.post` do jQuery aceita uma função para retornar o que o PHP envia. Para o PHP tens de colocar mais código para podermos ajudar... tens alguma coisa já no PHP?

Comment: @Sergio não fiz,mas seria um select SELECT  FROM produtos where id=1; por exemplo,ele retornaria vários registros a partir dai eu queria percorrer os registros para colocar no gráfico

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Os dados voltam no *callback* do método `$.post`:

```
$.post('envia.php', {nome: nome}, function(dados) {
    // use os dados aqui
    // o uso exato vai depender do formato que o PHP
    // usou para serializar os dados para envio
});
```

Parece que você quer retornar objetos para o JS, então o PHP teria de enviar um JSON:

```
<?php
$vetor = array('x' => 10, 'y' => 20);

// envia dos dados para o cliente
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($vetor);
?>
```

Aí você poderia usá-lo assim:

```
$.post('envia.php', {nome: nome}, function(dados) {
    console.log(dados.x, dados.y);
});
```

Comment: Acho que entendi,para decodificar o JSON com o JQUERY é algo +- assim : array = jQuery.parseJSON(dados);?

Comment: Se o documento for servido com o content-type correto, o jQuery identifica e já decodifica o JSON pra você (já chega decodificado no callback).

Answer (score 2):

O terceiro parâmetro da função `post` é um `callback` que recebe os dados do servidor como parâmetro.

```
$.post('envia.php', {nome: nome}, function(dados) {
    console.log(dados);
});
```

No servidor, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
$dados = array( ... );
echo json_encode($dados);
```

Comment: Para decodificar o JSON com o JQUERY é algo +- assim : array = jQuery.parseJSON(dados);?

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira Exato. Você também pode utilizar a forma mais curta `var resultado = $.parseJSON(dados);` ou então também pode fazer da forma como o @bfavaretto colocou, setando no cabeçalho de resposta o tipo da resposta.

Comment: ,A minha maior dificuldade é seguinte:no meu console retornou
isso [{"iea_id":"1","man_ins_area_00":"0","man_ins_prod_00":"0","man_ins_area_05":"0",
"man_ins_prod_05":"0","man_ins_area_10":"0","man_ins_prod_10":"0","man_ins_area_13":"0",
"man_ins_prod_13":"0","id_cid":"1","id_cult":"1"},
{"iea_id":"2","man_ins_area_00":"0","man_ins_prod_00":"0","man_ins_area_05":"0",
"man_ins_prod_05":"0","man_ins_area_10":"0","man_ins_prod_10":"0",
"man_ins_area_13":"0","man_ins_prod_13":"0","id_cid":"2","id_cult":"1"}]"
Dois registros do banco de dados,tem alguma forma de eu acessá-los separadamente?